# Corda main repo v1.0 installation issue

Tags: corda

I have downloaded corda main repo v1.0, example repo and template repo. To get started i imported the main repo but got error saying "repository not found". so i downloaded the M14.0 milestone release and imported it but got same error. Inorder to build my CorDapp can i directly import template? or is it required to install main repo or milestone as first step?

Comment: Can you post the full error message you got when importing the repository please?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to install the main repo/milestone. Each Corda release is published online (e.g. here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.corda/corda), and the required Corda libraries will be downloaded and cached automatically when you import the template or example project.

Try following the instructions here: https://docs.corda.net/getting-set-up.html.

Comment: HI Joel,  I was able to import example repo successfully and test it. But when i am trying to import template, it is not successful. Also, run configuration didnt load             
Warning:<i><b>root project 'cordapp-template-java-release-V1': Unable to resolve additional project configuration.</b>
Details: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'projectConfiguration' for DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='project ':cordapp-contracts-states'', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultProjectDependency.</i>

Comment: also, https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases update is showing error

Comment: Are you able to access the URl https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/corda/1.0.0/corda-1.0.0.pom? Also, see https://discuss.gradle.org/t/what-is-the-projectconfiguration-property-and-how-do-i-fix-the-fact-it-is-missing/22420/4 - are you able to upgrade IntelliJ/re-import the project from scratch? Does that solve the issue.